# Php mysql login form $row not working

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

i created login form with php or mysql but it has problem. When i log in and press submit there i see a blank site.
This is form handling page:

```
 <?php
 define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
 define('DB_NAME', 'loginform');
 define('DB_USER','user');
 define('DB_PASSWORD','pass');

  $con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
  $db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
/*
  $ID = $_POST['user'];
  $Password = $_POST['pass'];
  */
  function SignIn()
  { 
  session_start();   //starting the session for user profile page
  if(!empty($_POST['user'])) //checking the 'user' name which is from index.html, is it empty or have some text 
 { 
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM UserName where userName = ".$_POST['user']." AND pass = ".$_POST['pass'].") or die(mysql_error()); 
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error()); 
 if(!empty($row['userName']) AND !empty($row['pass']))

     {
 $_SESSION["a"] = "a";           
 $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];
 $_SESSION['userName'] = $row['pass'];
          echo "Succesfully login, redirecting to member page.";
 header("Location: http://192.168.100.13/member");

 }
     else
     {
             echo "Wrong password or Name try again";
  }
  }
  }
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
     SignIn();
  }
  if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
   header("Location: http://192.168.100.13/login");
 } 
 ?>
```

Mysql table look like this

```
+------------+----------+------+
| UserNameID | userName | pass |
+------------+----------+------+
|          1 | user     | pass |
+------------+----------+------+
```

I think the problem is in line 9 in the php code, because i ran code with CodingGround.

Comment: Notice: mysql-lib is deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO instead. Your script is also vulnerable to sql-injection.

Comment: What is "login" in "header("Location: http://192.168.100.13/login");? Is it a file? Is it a directory? Maybe "login" needs an extension like ".php", if it's a directory maybe it should have a file inside named "index.php".

Comment: you also should also store only secure hash values instead of the original password in your database. Use php's [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) here.

Comment: @AbcAeffchen This is only localhost site for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a quote where you shouldn't, and are missing them where they should be.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM UserName where userName = ".$_POST[user]." AND pass = ".$_POST[pass].") or die(mysql_error());
```

This line should be:

```
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM UserName where userName = "' . $_POST['user'] . '" AND pass = "' . $_POST['pass'] . '"') or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: `$_POST[user]` also does not look valid until `user` is not defined as a constant. It should be `$_POST['user']`.

Comment: Good point. I just went for the obvious one. I'll update. Thanks!

Comment: Now not showing blank screen, now showing:  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: @jusola  In a query you have to enclose strings with `'`. So use `"... userName = '" . $_POST['user'] . "' ..."`

Comment: @jusola - you need to wrap the username and password in your SQL in quotes, else they'll be interpreted as column names. Though you really, really should look at moving to `mysqli` or `PDO`, and using a prepared statement for this - adding user-provided data directly in an SQL statement is asking for trouble.